# SQL Server 2008 SSIS: Importing date field incorrectly (from Oracle)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, import, ssis

The date fields in the file (CSV) I must import are in the format `DD-MMM-YY`, SQL Server is importing them as `YY-MM-DD`. So `01-FEB-13` is imported as `2001-02-13`.

How can I change the format SQL uses to import the dates?

I don't have access to the original Oracle database, only the flat file exported from it. So everything I do pretty much has to be done in SQL.

Comment: Have you considered importing them into a character field and then using `convert` to extract the date?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I've no idea how to do that.

Comment: . . I always bring external data into a staging table and then process it in the database.  I would then do the date conversion as a SQL query that reads from the staging table and outputs into the final table.

Comment: Ohh I see now. That makes perfect sense.

Comment: @GordonLinoff if you make an answer for that I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the date format that SQL Server uses by default would require mucking around with the Windows server culture settings. **Not** a good idea, especially if this is the only file where you're having this issue.

I would use a Script Transformation and the .NET Framework's [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) method, which lets you completely control the expected format. Start by configuring the Flat File Connection Manager that you're using to read the CSV files so that the columns with the DD-MMM-YY dates have their `DataType` set to `string` or `Unicode string` rather than `date`, `database date` or any other date-specific type:
[image]

In your Data Flow, place a Script Transformation between your source and destination components, like thus:
 [image]

Select each of the DD-MMM-YY date columns as inputs to the Script Transformation:
[image]

And create an output column with a `DataType` of `date` corresponding to each input column:
[image]

The Script Transformation code will look like this (using C#)

```cs
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Globalization; // needed for CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    public override void IncomingRows_ProcessInputRow(IncomingRowsBuffer Row)
    {
        string incomingFormat = "dd-MMM-yy";
        Row.ConvertedCreateDate = DateTime.ParseExact(
            Row.CreateDate, 
            incomingFormat, 
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Row.ConvertedLastUpdateDate = DateTime.ParseExact(
            Row.LastUpdateDate, 
            incomingFormat, 
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't worked with Script Transformations before, so I'm gonna take the long route and use the staging table idea and use C# as a middle man to import it all. Thanks so much for the comprehensive answer though! I'm sure someone will google this and find it very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the to_char() function in oracle to format your dates so that they are in the format you want.  Hopefully Gordon's comment about storing as text referred to a staging table.  For a variety of reasons, your first import should be into a staging table anyway.

Comment: I don't have access to the Oracle database to change the format. Also, it is in its own staging table/database. Once I've got it imported fine I need to map it to our own tables.